# Apache Mod_ReWrite http header "X-RHN-Provisioning-MAC-0: eth0 de:ad:be:ef:04 " to be included on URL

Tags: ruby, apache, http, mod-rewrite, centos6

We are massaging a prev working ruby [kickstart](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-kickstart2-startinginstall.html) script to try to try to check headers coming in from a bare metal machine pxe booting(using the kssendmac kickstart option linked above). We built it around [cgi](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html) (which is where we are running into a problem). It looks like the headers are getting stripped before they get to the script. Is there a way we could use mod_rewrite or something else to grab the mac address section of the header and append it to the URL? something ala kickstart.ourdomain.com/cgi-bin/kickstart.rb?macaddress=$MAC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. there is.
I just was playing around with it 'cause you gave me a fun puzzle.
Here's what I came up with.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#prevents redir loops
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*)macaddress(.*)$
#swap the comments if you want to send a http 302 to the client, instead of doing the
#redirects internally in mod_rewrite
#RewriteRule kickstart.rb kickstart.rb?macaddress=%{HTTP:header-name} [QSA,R,L]
RewriteRule kickstart.rb kickstart.rb?macaddress=%{HTTP:header-name} [QSA,L]
#QSA causes the engine to append to the query string, instead of
#overwriting it
#L indicates that it is the last rule that should run, probably redundant here,
#but may be relevant in the scheme of a larger instance
#R means "Send redir to browser" instead of keeping it internal
```

Hope this helps you.
Where to put this config is an exercise left to the reader, but in my case, this was put in an htaccess file.